# Why pdo doesn't work for queries that's have space character?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I connect to database with PDO .
But when i have variables with values that's have space character it doesn't show anything for me:

```
require_once('db.php');
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM db1_etchat_user WHERE etchat_username =    :name and etchat_userpw = :pass');
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $username,':pass' =>$password));
foreach ($stmt as $row){
$privilegien=$row['etchat_userprivilegien'];
}

if (!isset($privilegien)!=="admin"){echo"false";exit;}
```

if `$privilegien` value have variable contains space character such as "hello you" it echo "false".
How I can resolve it?

Comment: what shall this comparison `if (!isset($privilegien)!=="admin")` do? decomposed: `NOT isset($privilegien)!=="admin"` but AFAIK isset returns a boolean which is then compared to a string which is never true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) returns `boolean`;
2. you combining 2 separate operations in your `if()`, try boolean logic operators `and` or `or` to summarize;
3. `'hello you' != 'admin'` so it's resulting `echo 'false'`;

Try this:

```
if (!isset($privilegien) || ($privilegien !== "admin")){echo"false";exit;}
```

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran thanks. I just hope it will help OP with his issue.

Comment: I use this but it don't work for me and echo false for me. $privilegien exists and has value and I can see it's value by echo . but it show "false" for me.

Comment: @user3199544 could you supply output of `var_dump($privilegien);` to the question?

Comment: Yes , when I get data from database with values that's contain space character it show NULL ,

Comment: @user3199544 provide a resultset, update the question with it.